# Drive motor voltage / other specifications of Roomba 650

Tags: motor, pwm, irobot-create, h-bridge, roomba

I salvaged some parts off my dead Roomba 650, and I'm trying to use the drive motor assembly . I got the pinout of the connector but I don't know what voltage / PWM / other specifications are there for this motor.

I've attached the picture of the drive motor assembly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Pratik

[image: Drive motor unit]

Edit: The Image is here: [Drive Motor Module](https://plus.google.com/photos/+PratikPanchal2011/albums/6119164925515534577/6119164929351874418?authkey=COOW4Njkmr7xQg&pid=6119164929351874418&oid=106454827636977474727)

Comment: Have you taken the motor completely out of the housing and looked for a part number?

Answer (score 1):

The motors get a PWM'd battery voltage which is around 18V.  I assume it is safe to run at that voltage at 100% duty cycle.  I imagine you could run a higher voltage but you run the risk of burning out your brushes.  Lower voltages work fine if your bot is small.  I have successfully run a small Roomba wheel module robot off of 8 AA batteries (about 12V).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, iRobot has released the spec for the motor interface here:

http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Wheel_Hack.pdf

Comment: Hi Ben,

Thank you for that link.
Unfortunately it is resulting in 404 error. Can you please repost the link, or the document itself to which it is pointing to?

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Well, the link works for me.  Maybe they had a temporary server issue.  Note that you can also get to the file by going to the main Create2 project page: http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx then clicking the "Create 2 Wheel Hack " link.

Comment: That link works for me; the document has also been archived by the web archive at https://web.archive.org/web/20150427160518/http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Wheel_Hack.pdf .